# change div class active

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following ul tag with div tag

```
<ul class="timeline">
  <li onclick="showThis(1);" class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__step">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red active></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Isert Code
    </div>
  </li>
  <li onclick="showThis(2);" class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__step">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Select Layout
    </div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

```js
$('selector').on('click', function() {
  $('selector').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

How to change `.timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red` to `.timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red.active` when it's clicked?

The script doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

You can use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) from jQuery.

```
$(".timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red").on('click', function(){
    $(".timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red").removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul').on('click', '.timeline__step__marker', function(e){
  var $this = $(e.target);
  
  $this.addClass('active');
  $('.timeline__step__marker').not($this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__step">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red active">Blah1</div>
    </div>
    <div class=" timeline__time ">
      Isert Code
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline__item ">
    <div class="timeline__step ">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red">Blah2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Select Layout
    </div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply works with following code. You can do this in a single line code.

```js
$('ul').on('click', '.timeline__step__marker', function(e){
  $(e.target)
    .addClass('active')
    .closest('li')
    .siblings()
    .find('.timeline__step__marker')
    .removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline__item">
    <div class="timeline__step">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red active">Blah1</div>
    </div>
    <div class=" timeline__time ">
      Isert Code
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline__item ">
    <div class="timeline__step ">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red">Blah2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Select Layout
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline__item ">
    <div class="timeline__step ">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red">Blah2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Select Layout
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline__item ">
    <div class="timeline__step ">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red">Blah2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Select Layout
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline__item ">
    <div class="timeline__step ">
      <div class="timeline__step__marker timeline__step__marker--red">Blah2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__time">
      Select Layout
    </div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```